# Assigning JS variable of a LWC(parent) to a Constant of another LWC(child)

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC specifically for Constants that can be used across our platform. I am importing this LWC wherever we need to reuse those constants. Now, I am trying to **dynamically** assign a value to the constants as below:

```
import { getAllConstants } from 'c/ConstantsUtility';
const CONSTANTS  = getAllConstants();

var foo = JSON.stringify(apiData).replace("-", "'_'").replace(" ","_");
console.log('CONSTANTS.TEMPORARY: ', CONSTANTS.foo); //Getting an error. 
fooMod = JSON.parse(foo);
console.log('fooMod ', fooMod);
console.log('CONSTANT.FOOMOD ', CONSTANT.fooMod);
if(CONSTANT.fooMod){
    console.log('CONSTANT.fooMod', CONSTANT.fooMod);
    return CONSTANT.fooMod;
} 
else {
    console.log('data ', apiData);
return apiData;
}
```

I have tried which errored out:

```
console.log('CONSTANTS.TEMPORARY: ', CONSTANTS.String(foo));
console.log('CONSTANTS.TEMPORARY: ', CONSTANTS.foo.toString());
```

How can I dynamically pass the value of 'foo' to the CONSTANTS, that way I can get the value of the CONST from the child LWC (ConstantsUtility).

Comment: What does "getting an error" mean? What is your implementation of getAllConstants? How are we supposed to help you with pieces missing?

Answer (score 1):

In order to force read-only properties recursively, I wrote a readOnlyProxyHandler. This is by no means fully tested, but should work for the purposes of this answer.

```
// readOnlyProxyHandler.js
const readOnlyProxyHandler = ({
  get: function(target, key) {
    if(key === Symbol.iterator) {
      return target[key].bind(target);
    } else if(typeof target[key] === 'object') {
      return new Proxy(target[key], readOnlyProxyHandler);
    }
    return target[key];
  },
  set: function() {
    return false;
  },
  deleteProperty: function() {
    return false;
  },
  enumerate: function(target) {
    return new Proxy(Object.keys(target), readOnlyProxyHandler);
  },
  ownKeys: function(target) {
    return new Proxy(Object.keys(target), readOnlyProxyHandler);
  },
  has: function(target, key) {
    return key in target;
  },
  defineProperty: function() {
    return false;
  },
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor: function(target, key) {
    return (key in target)? {
      value: typeof target[key] === 'object'? new Proxy(target[key], readOnlyProxyHandler): target[key],
      writable: false,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    }: undefined;
  }
});
export default readOnlyProxyHandler;
```

We can then wrap our constants in this read-only handler to avoid accidental writes or modifications to the constants outside of their file:

```
import readOnlyProxyHandler from 'c/readOnlyProxyHandler';
const data = { 
  message: 'Hello World' 
};
export const CONSTANTS = new Proxy(data, readOnlyProxyHandler);
```

And finally, we can import those constants to use them as we desire:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { CONSTANTS } from 'c/constants';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  get demo() {
    return CONSTANTS.message;
  }
}
```

I wrote this up in to a [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/Y8jhE59emG1AIxfzAuWE/src/app.js).

This proxy implementation may have several bugs with it, it's not meant to be bullet-proof, but it does prevent most common problems with constants, including accidentally deleting values, assigning values, etc, and it should work okay with recursive structures as well, if you desire. Feedback on any bugs you find would be appreciated.

Comment: I will add more details to my question by tomorrow AM. Also, I will try the way the above 'readOnlyProxyHandler' approach and will let you know.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. That's fine. This is really like my second-ever proxy implementation, but it seems to work okay in the demo, but feel free to fork it and play around with it.